# Error with .val() and .length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check the length of a string on a password input and I am getting the alert all the time.

I defined a variable named `password` and made an If-statement like this:

```
var setpassSection = $("#setpass"),
finaleSection = $("#finale");
function nextStep (hide, show) {
    hide.fadeOut(300);
    show.fadeIn(300);
};
var password = $("#passGoesHere");
$(".passButton").on("click", function () {
    if (password.length >= 7) {
        nextStep(setpassSection, finaleSection);
    } else {
        alert("Introduce una contraseña con mas de 6 caracteres.");
    };
});
```

but when I try the code even if I put a passwrod of 1 bilion numbers it alerts me the `else`.

Comment: What do you think your `password` variable contains?

Comment: @Ondkloss letters, numbers...? Xd

Comment: It's interesting that you already included the `.val()` in your question title, even though it's nowhere in your code and is probably the important missing element.

Comment: @Medo42 I tried with each one but not both, that is what I was trying to explain Xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, You are finding the control length not the control value length

```
 if (password.val().length >=7)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
password.val().length
```

Because at the moment, you're using `length` property of a jQuery Object. Which won't be the thing you're needing to be used right now.

Comment: [It isn't undefined](http://api.jquery.com/length/). But of course it doesn't contain what the OP thinks.